# Android SQLLite Table Column Missing Error

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code to create:

```
private static final String TABLE_CURRENT_GAME = "current";
    private static final String C_KEY_ID = "C_id";
    private static final String C_SCORE_1 = "C_score_1";
    private static final String C_SCORE_2 = "C_score_2";
    private static final String C_K_1 = "C_k_1";
    private static final String C_K_2 = "C_k_2";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_CURRENT_GAME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CURRENT_GAME + "("
        + C_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + C_SCORE_1+"INT,"+C_SCORE_2+"INT,"+C_K_1+"INT,"+C_K_2+"INT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CURRENT_GAME_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CURRENT_GAME);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

and my code for inserting:

```
void addCurrentGameData(CurrentGameTable data) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(C_SCORE_1, data.getScore1()); // score player1
        values.put(C_SCORE_2, data.getScore2());//score player2
        values.put(C_K_1, data.getKseres1());//kseres player1
        values.put(C_K_2, data.getKseres2());//kseres player2
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CURRENT_GAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

where CurrentGameData is my constructor.

Then when trying to insert the table like that:

```
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

         /**
          * CRUD Operations
          * */
         // Inserting Contacts
         Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
         db.addCurrentGameData(new CurrentGameTable(1,2,3,4));
```

In my phone I get this error:

```
08-19 16:36:23.876: E/Database(3996): Error inserting current
08-19 16:36:23.876: E/Database(3996): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table current has no column named C_score_2: , while compiling: INSERT INTO current(C_score_2, C_k_1, C_score_1, C_k_2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
```

In my emulator I get this error:

```
08-19 13:48:19.036: E/AndroidRuntime(519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 13:48:19.036: E/AndroidRuntime(519): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: current: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM current
08-19 13:48:19.036: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
```

Other table created with the same syntax works properly but this, second one, does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example :

```
C_SCORE_1+"INT,"
```

create one column named C_score_1INT without type,

your code shoud be (whith space added):

```
     String CREATE_CURRENT_GAME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CURRENT_GAME + "("
      + C_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + C_SCORE_1+" INT, "+C_SCORE_2+" INT, "+C_K_1+" INT, "+C_K_2+" INT)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Manage Applications -> Your Application -> Clear all application data.

Maybe it is using an old table stored in the phone before you added this column in your table.

Comment: It does not work. Same message again. that column score_2 does not exist.